# Shuffle an Array algorithm - Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I'm coding a program meant to read a .txt full of links and unsort those on an array, so later on those can be visited randomly.

Here's what I have done (And it's not working :D):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Scan{

        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        String test = "";
        int i = 0;
        int temp = 0;


        Scanner link = new Scanner(new File("links.txt"));
        while(link.hasNextLine()){
            test = link.nextLine();
            temp++;
        }
        link.close();

        String[] links = new String[temp];

        Scanner urls = new Scanner(new File("links.txt"));

        for (i = 0; i < temp; i++)
        {
            test = urls.nextLine();
            links[i] = test;
            System.out.println("Sorted: " + links[i]);
        }
        urls.close();
        System.out.println("Size of LINKS: " + temp);        


                    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - //
                    //  Start of the unsorting algorithm         //
                    //  (It's just not working, need a new one)  //
                    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - //

        String[] copy = new String [temp];
        int[] used = new int [temp];
        for(i = 0; i < temp; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < temp; k++)
            {
                    int j = (int) (Math.random() * temp);
                    //System.out.println(j);
                    if (j == used[k])
                    {
                        k--;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        used[k] = j;
                        copy[j] = links[i];
                    }

            }
            System.out.println(links[i]);            
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: My current unsorting algorithm is displaying all the links on their starting order.

Comment: Do you know about `List` like `ArrayList` for example?

Comment: @Maljam I've heard of it, but I'm not familiar. Will that make that job easier?

Comment: yes are you OK with a solution involving `ArrayList`?

Comment: @Maljam Sure, that way I'll learn some new stuff :D

Comment: FYI - there is a standard shuffling algorithm, called the Fisher-Yates or Knuth Shuffle:http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/11model/Knuth.java.html OR http://www.dotnetperls.com/shuffle-java

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the second loop, where your are selecting a random index `j`, but you are checking if `used[k] == j` when you should be checking `Does the array used contain j`?

So one solution is to create a method `boolean contains(int[] arr, int val)` that checks if it is already present. Or another simple solution:

```
ArrayList<String> links = //read from file

ArrayList<String> unsorted = new ArrayList<String>();

while(links.size() != 0) {
    unsorted.add( links.remove( (int)(Math.random()*links.size()) ) );
}
```

You can use `unsorted.toArray()`, if you want the output in `String[]`

Comment: I see... I'll change that and see if it's fixed. Thanks!

Comment: I know he wanted to do it manually, but maybe nice to know, Collections has a shuffle method that does that for you: Collections.shuffle(list);

Answer (score 0):

Why are you reinventing the wheel?

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(links);
Collections.shuffle(list);
String[] copy = list.toArray(new String[temp]);
```

Your code would be a lot simpler if you used a `List` instead of an array.